# Cannot create AD Application with Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

```
C:\> $app = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "exampleapp" -HomePage "https://www.contoso.org/exampleapp" -IdentifierUris "https://www.contoso.org/exampleapp" -Password "Qwertyu123$"
New-AzureRmADApplication : Resource not found for the segment 'me'.
```

I can issue the same command using the owner account. The thing is this application has almost all possible permissions with Azure (including owner)

edit - command used to launch Azure session:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $env:tenant_id -ServicePrincipal `
   -Credential ([pscredential]::new($env:app_id,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $env:app_key -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

[image: permissions example]

Obviously I'm missing some permission(s), which one(s)?

> Body: {   "odata.error": {
>       "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
>       "message": {
>         "lang": "en",
>         "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
>       },
>       "requestId": "9c3bf711-c9ad-4883-a5cf-fa7926ccdf63",
>       "date": "2017-03-06T10:14:29"   } }

Comment: Did you use Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId *your-tenant-id* ?
Do you, as the person running the PowerShell script have enough authorizations ?

Comment: Under which creds do you run New-AzureRmADApplication? How did you provide them to PowerShell?

Comment: Oh! after posting my script below, I noticed you have added a line on how you were providing the creds. so the question is does the service-principal have enough rights to create the application in the tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess that would be some kind of transient failure cloud is famous for, nothing did I change yet this is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your error but failed, here is my testing steps:

1. In azure ad classic portal , I add a web app :
   [image]
2. Input app name,choose web app/web api ,input sign-on url and app id url :
   [image]
   [image]
3. config the permissions as your picture shown :
   [image]
4. In powershell ,run your Add-AzureRmAccount script and then create a new app ,both work fine:
   [image]

Please use fiddle to capture the http request of New-AzureRmADApplication , you will find that it performs a rest api :
[image]

You could use a online tool ,like jwt.io to decode your access token ,please check the “roles” claims , I config the app permissions as your picture shown , the roles will be :
[image]

And "aud" is https://graph.windows.net/ . If there is something i haven't noticed,please let me know.

Comment: so whats the point of doing this, if its configured exactly the same?

Comment: use Fiddler to grab the access token and check the roles/tenant , help you  check whether you have enough permission to complete that request in tenant.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using this script, which works:

```
# This script creates an Azure AD application.
# Before running this script you need to install the Azure RM cmdlets as an administrator. 
# For this:
# 1) Run Powershell as an administrator
# 2) in the PowerShell window, type: Install-Module AzureRM.Resources

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Active Directory Tenant. This is a GUID which represents the "Directory ID" of the AzureAD tenant into which you want to create the apps.
# Look it up in the Azure portal in the "Properties" of the Azure AD. 
$script:tenantId = '00000000-0abc-0000-abcd-ef0001111234' 

# Variables for the registration of the AAD application for the Web API Service
$script:serviceAadAppName = "exampleapp"
$script:serviceHomePage = "https://www.contoso.org/exampleapp"
$script:serviceAppIdIRI = "https://"+$script:tenantId+"/"+$serviceAadAppName


# Import required modules
Import-Module AzureRM.Resources

# Login to Azure PowerShell (interactive: you'll need to sign-in with creds enabling your to create apps in the tenant)
$creds = Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $script:tenantId


# Create the Azure Active Directory Application
# Note that if, at this point, you get an error: "New-AzureRmADApplication : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRMAccount to set up your Azure credentials"
# then you will need to run Clear-AzureProfile (you might have an expired token)

$serviceApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $script:serviceAadAppName -HomePage $script:serviceHomePage -IdentifierUris $script:serviceAppIdIRI

# Create the Service Principal and connect it to the Application
$servicePrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $serviceApplication.ApplicationId$serviceApplication.ApplicationId
```

It's possible then to add more stuff such as credentials as you did, either during the creation of the application, of afterwards (with Set-AzureRMADApplication)

Comment: so how does this help?

Comment: I had not initially understood that the title of your question was create an AAD application with credentials which are a service principal (I had rather understood: create both an AD application and it's service principal)
How this helps: this provides details that can be checked. Is your tenant Id a GUID (and the GUID of the AAD tenant you are targeting).